# Packaging multiple Python Files: Getting Import error

Tags: python, package

I am trying to figure out how to package a python project so that I can distribute it to some co-workers. 
When I run `python setup.py sdist --formats=zip` it creates a zip that I can `pip install` but when I run the file it can't import the class files I created.

Here is my file structure for the project (probably not correct, but I didn't fully structure this project with packaging in mind):

```
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── scanner
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── googleSheets.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── merakiJsonHandler.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   └── wifiTester.cpython-35.pyc
│   ├── credentials.json
│   ├── googleSheets.py
│   ├── info.json
│   ├── merakiJsonHandler.py
│   ├── scan.py
│   ├── whatWap.py
│   └── wifiTester.py
└── setup.py
```

''scan.py'' is our "main" script that brings together all the classes.  Here is what my setup.py looks like:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(name='att-scanner',
      version='0.1',
      description='Meraki Wap/Wifi Scanner',
      author='jsolum',
      author_email='*****',
      license='MIT',
      packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
      entry_points={
          'console_scripts' : [
              'mws = scanner:scan.py',],},
      install_requires=['pyspeedtest', 'requests', 'gspread', 'oauth2client',],
      include_package_data=True)
```

And here is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//anaconda/bin/mws", line 7, in <module>
    from scanner import scan
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scanner/__init__.py", line 1, in 
<module>
    from googleSheets import SheetsController
ImportError: No module named 'googleSheets'
```

Why can't `scan.py` import `googleSheets.py` and what do I do to make it import that and my other classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`from googleSheets import SheetsController` is an absolute import statement, so once your package is installed, you need to either use the package name:

```
from scanner.googleSheets import SheetsController
```

Or a [relative import statement](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-328.html)

```
from .googleSheets import SheetsController
```

Comment: *facepalm* you're right.  I thought I checked that!  Currently I am getting an error that says ``  sys.exit(scan())
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable``.  I am curious to why it's trying to call scan.py.  Does scan need to be renamed to __main__? (I think I read something like that earlier when I was troubleshooting).

Comment: @JamesSolum I'm not 100% sure, but It looks like your entry point is set to the module, rather than a function in the module. Try something like `scanner.scan:main`

Comment: I just saw this comment now, but yes that was it!  Thanks!